# Unable to read elements from a dynamic ASP.Net table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to read elements from a dynamic ASP.Net table.

The table is declared like so in the ASP page:

```
<table id="ItemTable" runat="server">
    <!-- Will be filled with the user items. -->
</table>
```

I'm adding to it items, which are declared with this class:

```
public void AddDiv(shopItem item, int count)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder myCPH = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("PageContent"); // since i'm in a child of a master page, First i'm finding the CPH
    HtmlTable Table = (HtmlTable)myCPH.FindControl("ItemTable");//In the page, I'm finding the table
    Control possibleInstance = Table.FindControl("AmountFor" + item.ID); // here i'm looking for an element in the table which should be declared if I already created that item.
    if (possibleInstance != null) // making sure there are no duplicates.
    {
        return;
    }
    //more meaningless code
    TextBox Amount = new TextBox();
    Amount.ID = "AmoutFor" + item.ID;
    // some more less relevant code
    myCell.Controls.Add(Amount);
    // even more meaningless code
    rows[rows.Count - 1].Controls.Add(myCell);
    foreach (var tr in rows)
    {
        ItemTable.Controls.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

And it works fine - the problem is, when I try to find duplicates, it finds the table - but it won't find the dynamically created cells. I set a breakpoint by the end of the `if` clause, and for some reason, although an element by the name `AmountFor2` was already declared, and the table was found - it cannot find the element with that ID, and it creates another duplicate div. I'm pretty sure that's because the element is created dynamically; so, my question is, how does one find dynamically stated elements?

Comment: Don't use static fields in ASP.NET, they will be shared across all requests(so every user) and also causes locks. Why don't you use a web-databound control like `Repeater` or `GridView`(which is also rendered as a table).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you give an example of the general format for a GridView that will contain all these?